# Is it possible to sign into Gmail only?

Tags: gmail, google-account

Normally when you sign into Gmail, it signs into your whole Google account - YouTube, Gmail, Google Search, etc… Is it possible to sign into only Gmail and leave the others not logged in?

From a quick Google search, it doesn't look possible to change this in Google accounts settings. Is there, for example, a Firefox extension that would do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. There could be a hack, but I am not aware of any method to accomplish this.

I would suggest using a separate browser session with the appropriate anonymity mode enabled (i.e. InPrivate, Private Browsing, Incognito mode) and make sure you untick the "keep me logged in" box and log out of the service after you're done. That will at least make sure your session isn't shared with other browser windows/sessions.

Obviously, you can still be tracked via IP and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail is “free” because you are tracked by Google for their data/marketing purposes and are automatically signed into everything else as a result.

Hate to break the news to you but when you sign into Google it is not for one specific service; that is just a “carrot on a stick” to get you to login. The beginning, middle and end goal of Google’s “free” services is to just get you on their system to begin with.

Meaning there is no way to turn any of this off via a client side setting: If Google wants you logged into all Google “apps” and not just one of them—like Gmail—that is the way it is.